# how to display the image from a specified directory

Tags: php, html, xampp

I put all image in D drive.
I run one website with xampp appliaction in C: drive.
in my page for display image:

```
<img src="file:///D:/bea/PRODUCT/LB0064_19112015_160229/11-19-2015%209-47-21%20AM.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
```

But it not display.
how to display image in D driver.
Thanks.

Comment: You should put image in your project file this is good practice to do coding.

Comment: It's impossible to link directly to a file outside of the web accessible area of the web server. in your case its www or htdocs folder

Comment: Because our website display images from other application, then it put images in D driver. that my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Apache typically you would create an `alias` that points to the specific folder location in your `http.conf` file. I've never used or even seen `xampp` but I guess there would be an equivilent method to do so in xampp?

[Creating an alias in xampp](http://willi.am/blog/2011/02/24/creating-xampp-alias-directories/)

Generally one would put all files in the server root but over time you'll have multiple projects and thus duplicates. By using an `alias` style setup for various folders ( images, javascript, xml etc ) they can be easily accessed from whatever project is running on the webserver at the time.

```
    Alias /D_images "D:/path/to/images/"
    <Directory "D:/path/to/images">
        Options MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Then, once the server has been restarted, you could access the files contained in the target directory like:

```
<img src='/D_images/picture.jpg' />
```

Comment: thats also how I set up my folder in desktop :) , its look more legit than the others

Comment: @Andrew its never a good idea to use xamp or wamp, and why the hell anyone wants to use xamp or wamp when production server will be linux based,seriously nothing would be more dumb than this, also you just need to apache host file

Comment: @NullPoiиteя I didnt say its a good idea to use xampp or wamp on production server. I just said this is how I used in my environment and this looks more approachable than the other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Put your image file inside your project folder itsel. That is the best practice. For example put the image in a folder named 'images' in your project folder and then do as follows

```
<img src="http://localhost/images/11-19-2015%209-47-21%20AM.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
```

Comment: Because our website display images from other application, then it put images in D driver. that my problem.

Comment: Then you have to create and alias in your apache conf file: Just check out http://willi.am/blog/2011/02/24/creating-xampp-alias-directories/

Answer (score 0):

Put your `image` inside the project folder in the directory of `htdocs` for it be be accessible.

```
<img src="PRODUCT/USER/FILE_NAME.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
```

This is the best way to access your image/file. Don't put them separate from your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this isn't the most elegant solution but it might help the one or another having this problem. You could create a symbolic link in the web directory to the target directory with your images like that:

Press Windows+R and enter "cmd", press enter. In the DOS prompt change directory to your web directory, e.g.

```
D:
cd \websites\mysite.com
```

Here create the symbolic link to the images directory like that:

```
mklink /D myimages D:/bea/PRODUCT/
```

This will create a link at D:\websites\mysite.com\myimages linking to D:\bea\PRODUCT.

Now you can display your images with

```
<img src="myimages/LB0064_19112015_160229/11-19-2015%209-47-21%20AM.png" class="img-thumbnail" alt="User Image" style="width: 100px;height: 100px;">
```